# Trouble with 'this' keyword in React styled components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am currently trying to work out using styled components, but I am having a hard time creating components like usual. More specifically, I am getting an error with the 'this' keyword, and passing properties.

In my main JavaScript file I try to create a component like this (normal to me):

```
let newStyledComponent = <HomePageDiv property1 = {property1} ... />
```

In HomePageDiv.js I have one constant that is the div, and one constant which is the keyframes that this div will animate:

```
import React from 'react';

import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

export const HomePageDiv = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: ${backgroundChange} 4s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
`

const backgroundChange = keyframes`
    0%, 100% {
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at ${this.props.xLeftPercent+`%`} ${this.props.yLeftPercent+'%'}, rgba(${this.leftR + this.leftRStep * 0}, ${this.leftG + this.leftGStep * 0}, ${this.leftB + this.leftBStep * 0}, 0.5), transparent),
                    radial-gradient(ellipse at ${this.props.xRightPercent+`%`} ${this.props.yRightPercent+'%'}, rgba(${this.rightR + this.rightRStep * 0}, ${this.rightG + this.rightGStep * 0}, ${this.rightB + this.rightBStep * 0}, 0.5), transparent);
    }

    ...

    99% {
        ...
    }
`

export default HomePageDiv;
```

Given this, why am I getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

And, similarly if I take away the 'this' keyword I would also get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styled components are written like a functional component, this implies that there is no this. What you can do is `${(props) => props.xLeftPercent}`.

Comment: Couldn't you also unpack it in the call? `${({ xLeftPercent }) => xLeftPercent}`

Comment: Does this mean that I can use this as if it were a variable, as in, could I manipulate the property like this:

${((props) => props.xLeftPercent) * 2}

Comment: First comment: yes destructuring is also allowed, was making it clear for the creator of this post.
For the second comment: yes you can do manipulations that won't mutate anything.